# accessing own XAMPP directory through shell putty

Tags: shell, xampp, putty

I am trying to compare directories from a shared host server and directories located in my own computer. Own computer has XAMPP as the server.

To compare these two directories, I need access to the directories in folder htdocs (i.e. XAMPP/htdocs/intended_folder)

I am able to connect to shared host with putty and execute shell commands

How can I connect to my own server with putty?

Thank you

Comment: Where from do you want to compare the directories? Are you at your home computer, at shared host server or on 3rd location? Perhaps you are not looking for PuTTY/shell access at all. Maybe some GUI SFTP/FTP client would be more appropriate for your task. Please try to explain better what you are after, you may get better answers.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl I go the answer I was looking for: how to grant putty client access to my computer's own server. I am working from my own computer, I assumed a person reading my question would assume this. What am I after? As I mentioned in my question, I am trying to compare two directories each located in a different server. I want to output the differences between these two to a file. Although FTP allows for visual directory comparison, I cannot output the differences to a file: http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-compare-recursively-the-content-of-two-directories-with-rsync/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run ssh or telnet server on your local server. If you are running Windows, you can try e.g. http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download for ssh server. Once installed, accept the generation of keys, run the program, accept firewall rule and add a new user. Then you should be able to connect using PuTTY on your localhost address.

However, it will basically give you the same command line access as by simply running cmd.exe. Also keep in mind that you may no be able to use the same commands, if your shared host server is running different type of operating system than your own computer.

Comment: About having the same command line access as the cmd.exe, I think that with cmd.exe I cannot shell connect to shared hosting environment. Is this correct? If I am mistaken, could you point me to some documentation where I can learn how to use cmd.exe to connect to shared host server. I'll download ssh server and follow your instructions. Thank you